# r data table in igraph edge attribute

Tags: r, data.table, igraph

I'm working with igraph r package and I define edge attributes that are r data.tables.
When I create the graph, it's correct, I can visualize attributes that contain a data table.

```
edge_attr(myGraph, "trigramInfo", index = 13270)
[[1]]
   wordId1 occTrigram
     22059          1
```

But When I write the graph in graphml format (write_graph instruction), all edges attributes associated with data tables are not in the grapml file (xml text).

Is this a bug or do I have to choose another format to save data tables attributes?